# Property checked doesnt exist as the html element in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

property checked doesn't exist in type element in typescript?

```
toggle(source) {
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i] != source) 
        checkboxes[i].checked= source.checked;
}
```

Comment: use `checkboxes[i] as HTMLInputElement`. `(checkboxes[i] as HTMLInputElement).checked= source.checked;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens becuse only `HTMLInputElement` have the `checked` property in typescript. So, you just need use type-argument for this like:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLInputElement>('input[type="checkbox"]');
```